# Как выполнить JavaScript с сайта из Python 3 не используя Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Всем привет. Возникла проблема. Нужные мне данные для парсинга подгружаются на сайт после клика по кнопке. Как программно можно кликнуть по кнопке на сайте из python скрипта? В какую сторону копать? Selenium не предлагать, страшная вещь.

Comment: При нажатие на кнопку  на стороне клиента отправляется запрос на сервер? Посмотрите код который отправляется с клиента для начитки данных.

Comment: @DmitryErohin Нет, запрос не отправляется и url не меняется. Данные страницы есть, просто их очень трудно достать. А после выполнения какого-то скрипта легче. Получается нужно достать страницу после выполнения сценария на странице, а как это сделать я не знаю. С помощью pyqt5 можно и сейчас гуглю этот вопрос.

Comment: Как клиент получает данные при нажатие на кнопку? Через ajax?

Comment: @DmitryErohin, оказывается дело не в кнопке. После отработки какого-то скрипта меняется структура html. Данные достать легче. Вот как получить страницу с отработанным скриптом?

Comment: Вам нужно сформировать запрос такой как отправляет аjax и обработать его. Поможет библиотека request

Comment: @DmitryErohin `requests`